# How to add multiple headers to file_get_content in PHP

Tags: php

```
$opts = array('http' => array('method' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
                              'header' => array("Accept-language: en\r\n",
                                                "Cookie: " . session_name() . "=" . session_id() . "\r\n",
                                                " Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"),
                              'content' => $_POST));
$postdata = http_build_query($_POST);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

session_write_close(); // This is the key

echo $obsah = file_get_contents("http://localhost/journal/", false, $context);
```

This code is not working with [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) and cookies.

Comment: Why is there a space before `Content-type`? Is a leading space on a line in the HTML header allowed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**The two existing answers are incorrect.**

Newlines (`\n`) do not need to be added to HTTP headers used in `stream_context_create()`, and furthermore Carriage Returns (`\r`) should never be used anywhere near HTTP.

The following code is copied from the OP and corrected:

```
$postdata = http_build_query($_POST, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
        'header' => array(
            "Accept-language: en",
            "Cookie: " . session_name() . "=" . session_id(),
            "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        ),
        'content' => $postdata,
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$obsah = file_get_contents("http://localhost/journal/", false, $context);

echo $obsah
```

I've also added commas to the last array items so that maintenance will not have unnecessary lines in Git / SVN commits, and configured http_build_query() to use the more modern RFC 3986 encoding.

Comment: In the original, there was a space before `Content-type`. Does it matter or not?

Comment: @PeterMortensen No, it does not. I find it far more common to find HTTP requests and code with the space that without it.

Answer (score 2):

When passing a header with an `array()` instead of a string, you don't need the `\r\n` because PHP's `stream_context_create()` will do it for you on the header.

You also don't need `session_write_close()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass multiple headers there should two `\r\n` before sending POST data.

Let me explain.

**Try this:**

```php
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
        'header' => array(
            "Accept-language: en\r\n",
            "Cookie: ".session_name()."=".session_id()."\r\n",
            "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n"
        ),
        'content' => $_POST
    )
);

$postdata = http_build_query($_POST);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

session_write_close();   // this is the key

echo $obsah = file_get_contents("http://localhost/journal/", false, $context);
```

Comment: "Let me explain" followed by "try this" is not explaining.

Comment: In the original, there was a space before `Content-type`.